# Passing double diamension array to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am facing problem in passing double dimension array to controller in MVC.

```
var rowData = {};
rowData [0]["PK"] = "1234";
rowData [0]["index"] = 1;
rowData [1]["PK"] = "2345";
rowData [1]["index"] = 2;

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test/TestAction",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'ID': rowData,

            }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
             ....................
            ......................
```

In Controller i am action method, as given bellow.

```
enter code here
public ActionResult TestAction(string[][] ID){
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `var rowData = [{PK:"1234", index:1}, {PK:"2345",index:2}];`

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a horrible practice and is deprecated. You will see warnings in browser console regarding the deprecation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about creating class warping your data

```
public class Item
{
public int index { get; set; }  
public string pk { get; set; }
}
```

then your action would be like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(List<Item> items)
{
   //your code
   return Ok();
}
```